# Select with multiple critera and subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called os_files that contains all information for an uploaded file, and also os_files_downloads that stores a record each time a file is downloaded.

I want to delete records from os_files that has not had any downloads since it was uploaded, or where the last download was 30 days or older. I have the following code so far, but it doesn't seem to work, can someone point me in the right direction? Also I understand sub queries are slow, is there a quicker way?

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `os_files`
WHERE `uploadTime` < DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND `id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `fileId`
     FROM `os_files_downloads`)
  OR `id` IN
    (SELECT `fileId`
     FROM `os_files_downloads`
     WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: For best results, please define "doesn't seem to work". Do you get an error message? No results? Wrong results?

Comment: Hi there, I get no results at all. I have tried it with the file id not being in the download table, in which it should return a value, and also with it being in the download table and the last download value being older than 30 days

Comment: If the query added by me is working then please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to delete all ids not downloaded in the last 30 days. Logically this set will also include any ids that have never been downloaded:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `os_files`
WHERE `id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `id`
     FROM `os_files_downloads`
     WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

EDIT:

Assuming that `os_files_downloads.id` is NOT the foreign key, then you would need this:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `os_files`
WHERE `id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `os_files_id`   --or whatever the foreign key IS called
     FROM `os_files_downloads`
     WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

Comment: Hi @StevieG I just tried this with some sample data, showing the last download as today, but it still selected the file.

Comment: Can you post some of the sample data? Are you sure that `os_files_downloads.id` is the foreign key? Do you have an `os_files_downloads.os_files_id`?

Comment: Stevie, I realised my mistake and I updated my answer. Your solution is returning a file that was last downloaded in July, which is correct, but is also returning the file if I change the last download timestamp to today.

Comment: @SeanDarrenDawn - sorry, but that can't happen. The logic is pretty simple and clear. Are you sure you committed your change? Looking at your answer below, the logic is fundamentally flawed, you'll exclude the file, but for the wrong reasons, meaning you'll exclude other stuff as well that you dont want to.

Answer (score 0):

Here everything is fine you just need to replace the **'id'** field **from sub query** by the **foreign key** present in **`os_files_downloads`**, May be **`os_files_id`** and have to **add bracket** after **WHERE**

**Example:**

`SELECT id
FROM os_files
WHERE (
   uploadTime < DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND id NOT IN
      (SELECT os_files_id
       FROM os_files_downloads)
)
  OR id NOT IN
    (SELECT os_files_id
     FROM os_files_downloads
     WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY))`

Got the mistake try changing **OR id IN** by **OR id NOT IN** and in last line **timestamp < DATE_SUB** by **timestamp > DATE_SUB**

**See the query given above**

Comment: you're correct, I forgot to change the foreign key, but this is still returning no results.

Comment: Your solution is returning a file that was last downloaded in July, which is correct, but is also returning the file if I change the last download timestamp to today.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, after fiddling around I finally did it! Answer is below, thanks for your help and pushing me in the right direction!

```
SELECT id 
FROM os_files 
WHERE uploadTime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT fileId 
               FROM os_files_downloads) 
OR id NOT IN (SELECT fileId 
              FROM os_files_downloads 
              WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```